# JQuery function - Run it automatically once a day instead of a on click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, automatic-updates

We have a WordPress theme serving as an online directory. This theme uses a JSON file to display our listings on our map. For each of our modifications on a listing we must click on a button named "JSON Generator" to update the data of the map.

The problem is that we are currently adding/modifying a lot of content on our map so it requires a lot of manual regenerations.

[Screenshot of the button and the HTML declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtYQb.png)

Is there a way to replace the click launch of the JavaScript function regenerating the JSON by an automatic launch every 24 hours for example?

Here is the start of my actual .js file :

```js
;(function($) {
  // Json Generator
  var directoryManagerAdmin = function() {
    this.param = lava_dir_admin_param;
    this.init();
  }

  directoryManagerAdmin.prototype.constructor = directoryManagerAdmin;
  directoryManagerAdmin.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;

    $(document)
      .on('click', '.lava-data-refresh-trigger', this.onGenerator())
      .on('click', '.fileupload', this.image_upload())
      .on('click', '.fileuploadcancel', this.image_remove())

    $('button[data-listing-type-generator]').each(function() {
      var listingType = $(this).data('listing-type-generator') || false;
      var Instance = self.onGenerator(listingType);
      $(this).on('click', Instance);
    });

    self.bindJsonEditor();
  }

  directoryManagerAdmin.prototype.onGenerator = function(type) {
    // THEN YOU HAVE THE VERY LONG FUNCTION...
```

I think that I have to replace the launcher: `.on( 'click', '.lava-data-refresh-trigger', this.onGenerator() )` with an automatic launcher every 24 hours or so.

I found out how to get the current date: `var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();`, I also know that I may have to use the `setInterval` action but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks by advance if you have any clue to help me !

Comment: Client side JS only runs when the page is open in a browser. If you want this to run every 24 hours, that's not a workable solution. I'd suggest you research something like a CRON job to run a script (which you'll need to write, as it won't be in client-side JS) for you every N interval

Comment: If you have a browser open all day, `setInterval` could help. As this is a well documented function, why not check how to use it?

Comment: This appears to be more of an architectural problem. For example, I've had to run a periodic refresh on a server, but this is not problem that a webpage can solve. You need something like a service on your webserver (i.e. .NET Core Worker Service, Cron job, etc).

Comment: You could use local storage to make workable solution despite refreshing your browser. However probably you should avoid this doing altogether on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. I understand the problem. It will be too hard to make the script for the CRON job by my own. I will stick to the manually way that I use for now. Thanks again.